# How to change the background color of an input field on error jquery validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

My problem is that when i have an input field that is not valid i cant change the color of the background field, i could change the color of the error msg but i want the field with a red background and borders...
My code:

**HTML**

```
#put here some html so you can see some of the input fields

<div class=".container ">

<form id="miForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" id="dni" name="dni" type="text" placeholder="Dni" />
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" id="historiaclinica" name="historiaclinica" type="text" placeholder="Historia Clinica" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" id="cuil" name="cuil" type="text" placeholder="Cuil" />
    </div>
</div>    
</form>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

input[type="text"].claserror{
color:#DF0101;
background:#DF0101;
}

erele.claserror {
color:#DF0101;
}
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$("#miForm").validate({
errorClass: "claserror",
validClass: "clasevalida",
errorElement: 'erele',
    rules: {
        nombre: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        },
        razon_social: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true,
            maxlength: "25"
        },
        especialidad: {
            required: true
        },
        matriculaprovincial: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        },
        matriculanacional: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        },
        apellido: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        },
        dni: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: "8",
            maxlength: "8"
        },
        cuil: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: "10",
            maxlength: "11"
        },
        nacimiento: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        correo: {
            email: true
        },
        direccion: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: "25"
        },
        telefono: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        },
        celular: {
            digits: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        },
        sexo: {
            required: true
        },
        historiaclinica: {
            required: true,
        maxlength: "20"
        },
        osocial: {
            lettersonly: true,
            maxlength: "20"
        }
    },
messages: {
    nombre: {
        lettersonly: "Escribe sólo letras"
    },
    apellido: {
        lettersonly: "Escribe sólo letras"      
    },
    osocial: {
        lettersonly: "Escribe sólo letras"      
    },
    razon_social: {
        lettersonly: "Escribe sólo letras"
    }
    },
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent('.miForm').addClass('error');
    },
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent('.miForm').removeClass('error');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess you mistyped your class container `<div class=".container ">`?

Comment: you mean that i have to change "form-control" to ".container".. the page runs perfectly.. the problem is that when i have an error the input field keeps like before, i want it with red color and borders..

Comment: nope I'm just wondering why do you have a **dot (.)** in your class? you might get conflicts with that especially when you use jquery

Comment: if i just type "container" the input fields dont keep in their place.. its useful

Comment: maybe you have a css for **container** then? because I'm quiet sure .container won't work with css

Comment: correct.. 
.container{
   height: 80%;
   width: 0%
}
thats it (in css, i didnt write it in the code cause i thought it was useless)

Comment: when you call `.container` in your style sheets it is not calling that parent `<div>` its not calling anything.. the `.container` in your stylesheet is only looking for an element with a class `container` and not **.container** remember that dot(.) is a class selector that is why you should not do a class element with a dot. For more info about class selector you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: well i did it.. change just the name of the class to "container" instead of ".container".. it works well but i keep my trouble of the input field.. if someone knows plz help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys I have found the problem.... in the section controlling the highlight I was missing the line of code that added the error class so nothing was happening.. here is what I did:

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent('.miForm').addClass('error');
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); #this one for highlight the input
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent('.miForm').removeClass('error');
    $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass); #this one for unhighlight the input
}
```

thanks to the people who tried to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when i have an input field that is not valid i cant change the color of the background field

You're directly breaking it here...

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent('.miForm').addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent('.miForm').removeClass('error');
}
```

The `unhighlight` and `unhighlight` functions are designed to apply the error and valid classes to the input elements.  Your custom functions above are over-riding the default behavior.

Remove or adjust these functions appropriately.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yn1podbe/**

Answer (score -2):

Get Rid of the . in your class container for starters

Comment: plz i have a poor English, i couldnt understand

Comment: He says - Remove the dot in this line of code <div class=".container ">

Comment: i did it.. but it keeps the same problem, idk if my code its rigth, i just need the input field in red when its an error

Comment: this should be written in the comment section and not as an answer :)

Comment: You can use a regular onsubmit event handler and loop through the elements check for null or empty String if so  set the style of that element to the specified background color.

Comment: **You can use a regular onsubmit event handler and loop through the elements check for null or empty String if so set the style of that element to the specified background color.** add this to your answer, it might help peoples in SO :)